# onclick function on a button in an embedded html in js file not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string which has embedded html in it which is in js file. I have an onclick funtion on a button which calls a js function. but the control is not going inside the function.

```js
info += "<html><body bgcolor='#f1f7fe'><b>" +
     "<input type=\"button\" onClick=\"sendVehicleId()\">button text</input></a></b><hr>" + 
            "</body></html>";

function sendVehicleId()
  alert("hello");
}
```

I dont know whats wrong in this

Comment: Give us demo link and format your code in question.

Comment: why there is "+" in your html?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issues in you code.

1 : You html code may have some issues. (Missing `<a>` tag)

2 : Where do you "inject" this html ? Could you show the web page where you have your html ?

Go to your page, then "inspect element" and see if your button has a onClick tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, then try the `.on('click', function(){})` method & call the function here rather than directly adding it in the element declaration. Dynamically added elements are sometimes missed/ignored in DOM. Hope this helps.

Comment: Aalok you will be down voted, because user asked specifically for JavaScript and HTML, so .on function will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Html is not in proper format,

here is sample which works fine at my end.

```
var info = "<html><body bgcolor='#f1f7fe'><b><input id=\"btnOnclick\" type=\"button\" onClick=\"sendVehicleId()\">button text</input></a></b><hr></body></html>";

function sendVehicleId(){       
    alert("hello")      
}
```